# How to make my slider not showing empty slide on final slide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi i am very new to the coding world. I create a html image sidebar which display a picture and it has a auto slide function alongside nav button. The problem is it shown an empty slide before it started to return to slide one.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 8000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>W3.CSS</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <style>
    .mySlides {display:none;}
  </style>
  <body>

    <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
      <a href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/08/21/14/51/pet-423398__180.jpg">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/08/21/14/51/pet-423398__180.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </a>
      <a href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/08/15/02/pug-801826__180.jpg">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/08/15/02/pug-801826__180.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </a>
  

      <button class="slide-button-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
      <button class="slide-button-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for the help.

Here how it look like [Blank Picture on slide before going back to slide 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgrH1.jpg)

Comment: Based on your comment code, when we replace images by public image, we dont see any other "empty slide"

Comment: @MaxiGui weird. btw where do i put the js code? inside the html or using plugin? im currently doing it on wordpress so im not sure where to put, originally it inside the script html body

Comment: How ever you can because wordpress can really change it. Just make sure that wordpress is calling it and try to change the name of your function maybe it is using for something else by your thema

Comment: @MaxiGui ok noted. Yeah i also tried it on my vscode, it show no error, but when i run it on wordpress it will show blank slide before the next countdown back to slide one. I provide the image on the bottom of the post. Thank you again